# Sort php array by value compared to another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How can I sort an array based on another array?
I'm speaking about the values, not the keys. I've found plenty of questions about how to sort the keys but none about the values.

Imagine I have this array :

```
$sizes = array("L", "XXXL", "M", "S");
```

How can I reorder these to be like this :

```
$newsizes = array("S", "M", "L", "XXXL");
```

based on a fixed human logical array like this one :

```
$sizeincrement = array("XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "XXXL");
```

And considering elements that are not in the sizeincrement array should be appended at the end.

I thought this would exists as a ready-made sort function, but it appears it's not the case:  [PHP SORTING](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

Comment: array_intersect() will do the sort you need without resorting to custom functions or usort. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21004179/sort-php-array-by-value-compared-to-another-array/21004431#21004431).

Comment: @DigitalChris Though it's debatable whether intersecting, then diffing, then merging arrays is really a more efficient approach than usort. =)

Comment: @jszobody no, I think you missed the point. I ALSO answered his second part about "lements that are not in the sizeincrement array should be appended at the end."  The single line array_intersect accomplished what the other answers did.

Comment: Indeed the only wrong part is that elements not being present are prepended not appended http://3v4l.org/C2LtC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of common array functions can accomplish this:

```
<?php
$sizes = array("L", "XXXL", "M", "S");

$sizeincrement = array("XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "XXXL");

//this will give you the array you need in the order you need:
$sorted_array = array_intersect($sizeincrement,$sizes);

//now get the ones NOT in the array:

$missing_array = array_diff($sizeincrement,$sizes);

$final_array = array_merge($sorted_array, $missing_array);

var_dump($final_array);
?>
```

Here it is working:  https://eval.in/87279

Comment: Thanks Chris, this is the solution considering the last part of my question

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a custom `usort` callback function pretty easily. Something like this:

```
function compare($a, $b) {
    $sizeincrement = array("XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "XXXL");
    if(!array_search($a, $sizeincrement)) return 1;
    if(!array_search($b, $sizeincrement)) return -1;
    return array_search($a, $sizeincrement) > array_search($b, $sizeincrement);
}
```

Then call:

```
usort($sizes, "compare");
```

Working example: http://3v4l.org/2Hp0g

Comment: You forgot to add the ones NOT in the initial array at the end.

Comment: @VincentDuprez no look at his output: it has only 4 elements.

Comment: Upvoted your answer as it pointed me to the right path thanks, I will set Digital chris answer as correct answer as it is considering the missing elements..

Comment: @VincentDuprez Had to step away for a sec, sorry. Glad to help at least show you the right path, I'd strongly encourage sorting functions for this. Updated my answer, it's trivial to add more logic if needed for things like extra elements (or anything else you might need to take into account).

Answer (score 1):

A custom function can do the job really quickly ! here is my guest

```
$sizes = array("L", "XXXL", "M", "S");

function sort_size($arr) {
    $out = array();

    foreach (array("XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "XXXL") as $size) {
        if (in_array($size, $arr)) {
            $out[] = $size;
        }
    }

    return $out;
}

$newSizes = sort_size($sizes);
```

like that you can add or remove new sizes directly in the array in the foreach.

hope that help!

Comment: I think your answer is missing the case of some values not present in the reference array, They will be lost. I could be wrong

Comment: This gives the sorted $sizes, but doesn't append the missing elements to the end.